# How to set content/condition rules for saving data in the blockchain?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I can send a SMS to my blockchain (hyperledger fabric 2.0, node.js) to save the content of the SMS there.

Is it possible to set some content rules, so that not every content of a SMS can be saved in the blockchain?
For example, only numbers from 1 to 5 should be allowed to be saved and every other content should not be saved there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you save data to Fabric you do it by invoking chaincode. You can code any data format rules you want in the chaincode.

However, any client that has WRITE permissions on the channel can send a transaction to the ordering service, and it will end up part of the block, and there is no input sanitation done by the orderers.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think there is also a way trough HTTP Post? Or is the only way to change the chaincode?

Comment: The only way is to enforce it in the chaincode

Comment: Okay. Thank you!